# Why does listen `443 default_server ssl` work for multiple server names in nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I run nginx for static content and as a proxy to Apache/mod_wsgi serving django. I have example.com and test.example.com as proxy to Apache/Django and static.example.com which serves all static files directly through nginx. I have a wildcard SSL cert so that each of these sub-domains can use SSL (and I only have one IP).

Why is it that when using `listen 443 default_server ssl;` in *either* test.example.com *or* example.com, SSL works for both yet I have to explicitly listen to 443 for static.example.com?

```
ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/example.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/example.key;

server {
    listen      80;
    listen      443;
    server_name static.example.com;
    # ... serves content ...
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen      443 default_server ssl;
    server_name  example.com;
    # ... proxy pass to http://example.com:8080 (apache) ...
}
server {
    listen      80;
    # why don't I need `listen 443;` here?
    server_name test.example.com;
    # ... proxy pass to http://test.example.com:8080 (apache) ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SSL protocol by itself (without the [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) extension) uses the ip address of the server to request the SSL certificate. With SNI it also passes the hostname (doesn't work for Win XP), but that should't be relevant here.

Server directives are not an exact match. It's the "closest" match. It may appear "work", but it may be ending up in the wrong server directive. It's hard to tell without any more information, like the server root.

The point is something will always work since you appear to be using a single ip address.

Comment: I agree with Luke, it seems like it would work, but I would not rely on that configuration. You should probably explicitly add

    listen 443